# Price rule based on date

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I need to create a price rule that will decrease the product price by some percentage every day. I don't think it can be done with price rules, so any advice would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you create  several price rules, each active for one day only with discount like 5,10,15,20, ... percents?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible with a pricerule.
I would suggest creating a custom module with a daily cronjob that takes the special price of the product, subtracts a certain amount and sets that as the new special price.

Please check this excellent [Inchoo Tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/) on how to create a custom cronjob in Magento